# Listen to UDP or TCP in a web browser

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js, google-chrome, webserver

Is there any way to start a webserver in a browser ?

I need to be able to accept connections from c# running on another computer, I really don't care what technology I use as long as I can trigger javascript events on the "server" browser.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with the browser alone. You will need a listening party somewhere along the route between the browser "server" and the other computer. If there are only a limited number of clients and they are known, then you probably can reverse the role and make the clients the listening party and the browser page will actively poll the clients.

Comment: It is not clear from your original question, but this sounds like something that "SignalR" http://signalr.net/ would be great at enabling.

Answer (score 1):

You can't start "real" webserver in a browser (e.i there is no API and you are not allowed for security reasons to bind to and listen TCP port). However, if you connect to a HTTP server wich acts as a "bus" and forwards messages to you then you in essence have the same functionality. That's how [browserver](http://browserver.org/) works.